# Identity principle

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a problem with an exercise as follows: Is there a holomorphic function $f:K(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that:

$$f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)f'\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=1$$ or $$f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)f'\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}$$

I was able to notice that from the identity principle the formulas hold for all $z$, yet I don't know what to do next.

Comment: By $K(0,1)$ do you mean open ball of radius $1$ in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Perhaps you'd find it useful to notice that $ff'$ is exactly half the derivative of $f^2$.

Comment: @luka5z yes, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Expanded from my comment above)

Based on the observation that

$$f(z) f'(z) = \frac 1 2 \frac d {dz} \big(f(z)\big)^2$$

the first statement implies that $f(z)^2$ is identically equal to the function $2z$. See Daniel Fischer's comment for what this implies.

---

On the other hand, the second statement implies that

$$\frac{d}{dz} \big(f(z)\big)^2 = 2z$$

which has the non-constant solution $f(z) = z$.

Comment: $f(z)^2 = 2z + c$ for some constant $c$. If $\lvert c\rvert \geqslant 2$, you have a holomorphic branch of $\sqrt{2z+c}$ on the unit disk. (Welcome back, by the way.)

Comment: @DanielFischer True, I was only thinking of $c = 0$... (Thanks!)